# Unknown field "setHostnameAsFQDN" despite using latest kubectl client

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubectl, podspec

I have a deployment yaml file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-kubernetes
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-kubernetes
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-kubernetes
    spec:
      setHostnameAsFQDN: true
      hostname: hello
      subdomain: world
      containers:
      - name: hello-kubernetes
        image: redis
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
$ kubectl apply -f dep.yaml  

error: error validating "dep.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec): unknown field "setHostnameAsFQDN" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.PodSpec; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

My kubectl version:

```
$ kubectl version --client
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"20", GitVersion:"v1.20.0", GitCommit:"af46c47ce925f4c4ad5cc8d1fca46c7b77d13b38", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-08T17:59:43Z", GoVersion:"go1.15.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
```

After specifying `--validate=falsee`, `hostname` and `hostname -f` still return different values.

I believe I missunderstood something. Doc says that `setHostnameAsFQDN` will be available from kubernetes v1.20

Comment: post what version your k8s server is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You showed `kubectl` version. Your kubernetes version also need to be v1.20.  Make sure you are using kubernetes version v1.20.

Use `kubectl version` for seeing both client and server version. Where client version refers to `kubectl` version and server version refers to `kubernetes` version.

As far the k8s v1.20 release note doc: Previously introduced in 1.19 behind a feature gate, `SetHostnameAsFQDN`  is now enabled by default. More details on this behavior is available in [documentation for DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/#pod-sethostnameasfqdn-field)

Comment: Oh, poor me. Thank you for the clarification!
Server K8S turned out to be at v1.18.9